# get the ancestor nodes of a selected xml node using c# into a multiline text box

Tags: c#, xml

Im using c#.net. I have an xml file that contains many nodes. I have got the xml file into a tree view. Now when I select a particular node in the treeview, I should be able to display all its ancestors in a multiline text box. Please suggest me to do this job.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not really sure what you want but this might be some thing to start with.
The extension method will get the xpath to an `XElement` node with attributes to specify the exact element more precisely.

```
public static string ToXPath(this XElement element)
{
    var current = element.Parent;
    string result = "";
    while (current != null)
    {
        string currentDef = current.Name.ToString();
        string attribsDef = "";
        foreach (var attrib in current.Attributes())
        {
            attribsDef += " and @" + attrib.Name + "='" + attrib.Value + "'";
        }
        if (attribsDef.Length > 0)
        {
            currentDef += "[" + attribsDef.Substring(5) + "]";
        }
        result = "/" + currentDef + result;
        current = current.Parent;
    }
    return result.Substring(1);
}
```